# Remove repeated characters in a word

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to clean texts for a data set, and many of the words are misspelled, for example, many times I will see the word "hellllo." I wish to remove repeated characters where a character is repeated more than twice in a row. Obviously this will not work with words such as "nooooo" because that will convert it to "noo", but I have functions to handle this written already. All I want to do is convert words such as "hellllo" to "hello".

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide some code to show you tried!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic function that handles arbitrary number of repetitions allowed:

```
def remove_multiple(s, n=2):
    '''
    param s: string
    param n: number of max repetition allowed in the string
    '''
    if n < 0:
        return
    elif n==1:
        return ''.join(sorted(set(s), key=s.index))
    elif n > 1:
        temp = []
        temps = s + ' '*n
        for i, c in enumerate(s):
            if len(set(temps[i:n+1+i])) > 1:
                temp.append(c)
        return "".join(temp)

>>> remove_multiple('helllllllllllllllooooooooooooooo', 2)
Out: 'helloo'
>>> remove_multiple('helllllllllllllllooooooooooooooo', 5)
Out[]: 'helllllooooo'
```